# What would be the best way to making services run in background in the latest Android versions?

Tags: android, service

I want to make a `service`, which keeps running in background, and can withstand getting killed by swipe on task manager. I don't want the hacky alarm manager way. I have tried that already, the service still gets killed, although it gets restarted again. [Here](https://github.com/henrylilei/AlwaysOn) is a good example of such a hacky approach.

1) I want my service to keep running in android Oreo. [(I know this can be done through `JobScheduler`)](https://blog.klinkerapps.com/android-o-background-services/)

2) I don't want a notification.(notifications are fine, but I would prefer not to have any)

what would be the best approach? I know this is possible because I have seen this in a lot of apps. AND I am sure this is a problem every developer would face at some point. I have tried sticky service, but It does not work, It stops working as soon as I leave the app.

How are the [other apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=audio.sound.effect.bass.virtrualizer.equalizer&hl=en) on play store doing this?

Comment: Non Killable?  System service .

Comment: Whoever down voted, explain as to why? I know I am following the rules.

Comment: The combination of 1 and 2 from your question is not supported (outside of custom ROMs, or perhaps a rooted device).

Comment: Murphy, pretty sure this is possible. I have seen a lot of non root apps using this technique https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=audio.sound.effect.bass.virtrualizer.equalizer&hl=en

Comment: `"I don't want the hacky alarm manager way. "` you call it hacky? well....

Comment: @pskink yes, anything which stops on getting killed and restarts itself would considered hacky and unclean. Any other questions?

Comment: yes, one more question: why do you think you need such a service? what is it supposed to do when running all the time?

Comment: @pskink I need this for my equalizer project, which would manipulate the audio output applying effects like`BassBoost` from the `androidFx` class. And yes I have tried every single approach, but It does NOT work in the background.